# WebDriver Dropdown Menu Won't Stay Open

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

I'm working with Selenium / Java and having an interesting issue with a DropDown Box that fires an event... I can't use `Select` because the dropdown is using an organized list, not select and option (when the box is closed):

```
    <section id="..." class="ember-view">
     <ol id="...">
       <li id="...">
```

I successfully click on the dropdown box: `element.click();`
and the dropdown box opens!  But then it closes right back up again when the next line executes (which is just a `System.out.println("...");`).

I'm baffled.  I've tried

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver
jse.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).change()", element);
```

and

```
    jse.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).focus()", element);
```

and even

```
    jse.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).blur()", element);
```

both before and after I click on the dropdown box, but that little sucker just won't stay open!  When I print the value of arguments to the console `System.out.println(jse.executeScript("$(arguments[0]));`, arguments is null... I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Does the same behavior happens manually too? Does it remain open if you hover on it? Why not use JS itself to click on it?

Comment: No.  Manually, you click on it and it stays open.  I can't hover on it in automation, because once the next line executes, the menu disappears.  Executing a JS click has the same effect, as does using the Actions class and moving to the element, then performing the action.

Comment: Could you cheat and try using sendKeys to the dropdown element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do appreciate everyone for contributing, but I never actually found the reason this was happening.  So, I tried a cheat instead...

I put it all in a try / catch block, and that seems to slow it down enough to process the event.  Of course, the catch is useless because it will never be reached but it works.

It's a total hack, I know.  I'd still be interested in finding a reason for this behavior, but until then, we carry on!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not changing the classes when you click the dropdown then you're going to click it and it's going to just disappear after you click it pretty much. Try making it so the dropdown always shows and add a class that disappears on click called "hide" or "removeDisplay" like so

```
hide { display:none }
```

and then put it in the html element.

```
<htmlElement class="alwaysShowThis hide"></htmlElement>
```

make sure that on clicking it you remove the `hide` class, then you can just put a timer on it or just detect for when you are hovered over it.

the javascript might look like this:

```
display(event) {
  if(/*checkfor hide class existing*/){
     //remove hide class
  }
}
hide() {
  if(alwaysShowThis or its id is not being hovered over){
     //add hide class to its classes
  }
}
```

I mean these are just some 5 min suggestions, obviously there is a way to write these better but I don't have them off the top of my head, but you can find how to do all of these things quite easily.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Raults!  But I should state that I am only performing functional tests on the website... I didn't write it, and I don't have the ability to change the HTML.  The only thing I can do is interact with it through Selenium and Java (and maybe a few JS scripts through JavascriptExecutor).  I do appreciate the help though!

Comment: Ah yes, selenium, that does make a difference. You need to mess with the actual function that fiddles with the dropdown. Treating your test like an actual user works sometimes, but there comes a lot of issues in regards to timing and asynchronous stuff. Testing to see the javascript works is just as good as actually clicking for the dropdown in almost every case.

Comment: @Raults no it is not the same, a click action in code is not as good as actually clicking the dropdown in almost every case. There could be several use cases on user interaction with the frontend which needs the user like interactions else 100% unit tested code would be a bug free code which is not the case, :).

Comment: I would argue that there are very few cases that testing the actual clicks does you anymore good than testing timing of things, which in most cases its not necessary to do that. I mean, that there can depend on what you're using too, django, polymer, ruby, angular2, w/e, but I'd be a hard sell on it without someone explaining exactly why it's superior.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem and solved it with moving the cursor to the dropdown.

```
public void hover(WebElement element) {
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver());
    builder.moveToElement(element).perform();
}
```

After that it stayed open and I could click my selection.

Answer (score 0):

I now it's been a long time, but maybe someone has the same problem and all that is mentioned here already didn't help.
In my case I needed the dropdown to really stay open, because otherwise the time getting child elements was not enough.
Following did the trick for me (don't ask me why though):

```
    Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver); 
    actions.moveToElement(dropdown);
    actions.clickAndHold();
    actions.perform();
```